# Which Auth Method to Use?

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-drive-api

I want to have my PHP code to pull a file from Google Drive. If I do it without authentication, it returns: `(403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.`

Looking up authentication methods, authentication requires redirection or user login. I just want the server to acquire the authentication code itself without user prompt or redirecting.

What method can do this? Will someone please provide a guide and/or examples for the method? Thanks.

Comment: Am i understanding you correct? You want to access a Users Google Drive data with out prompting them for authentication?

Comment: I already found the answer, but what I was looking for was to access my own drive, not other users.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it's invalid. If you want to post your own solution, please do so properly by posting a self-answer which includes the actual solution you've found. See [Can I answer my own question?\(http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for information about how to do so in a proper manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a service account.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: this is a link only answer please post code with your answer on hiw you can use a service account to access his Google drive.